Time periodic Euler flows
What are some examples of solutions to the incompressible Euler equation on the torus $u:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{T}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (with $d\in \{2,3\}$)
$$\partial_t u+u\cdot \nabla u +\nabla p=0,\ \text{div}\ u=0$$
with the property that their flow is time-periodic? In other words, if you look at solutions of
$$\partial_t \phi(t,x) =u(t,\phi(t,x))$$
then $\phi$ is time-periodic.
In fact I don't need such a strong property, I'd be happy even if they were periodic only for initial data $\phi(0,x)=x$.
